# Sharepoint Online SPUtility.GetLocalizedString in WebPart

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-online

Trying to get localized content working on Sharepoint Online.

I followed the steps here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp179919.aspx#LocalizingAppWeb to create 2 resource files under Solution -> Features.

The structure of my solution right now is

```
Solution / Features / MyFeature / Resources.resx
```

What do I do to get a localized MyString through my code behind file (.cs) ?
Tried this:

```
String s = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:MyLabel;", "MyFeature", 1033)
```

and it didn't work.

Also what do I do to get the same string on my .ascx file ?
Tried this:

```
<%# $Resources:MyLabel,MyFeature %>
```

and also didn't work

Any clues ?

Comment: I also looked at this:
Walkthrough: Localizing a Web Part - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg491702%28v=office.14%29.aspx

But they're deploying to a farm so they have access to the Resources folder. I don't, in Sharepoint Online

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the MSDN article: [Localization of Sandboxed Solutions in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg615460%28v=office.14%29.aspx).

The first article describes how to use Satellite Assemblies which you can access through code to localize Web Parts, Event Receivers, ...

The second article describes how to use Feature Resources which you can access in the Feature xml file to localize the feature.

You usually need both approaches as you probably both want to localize how the feature shows as well as your UI and none of the approaches cover both.

Comment: Out of the two links the second one was the only one that came close and still nothing on how to actually call it.

Comment: That's because the callable resources is implemented as shown in the first. See expanded answer

Comment: Ok, much more work than I thought, but seems like the first one will be fine. Thanks